# Why is addon ocrtesserac not available in my g1ant software?

Tags: g1ant

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9GjE.png)

I am unable to use octetesserac addon. It is not available in my software, where do I find it?

Answer (score 0):

To use addon ocrtesseract you need to download it from manual.g1ant.com
first, go to manual.g1ant.com
then click addon ocrtesseract and then go to ocrtesseract.find command and then scroll down
there you will find
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Click that link "these steps" and follow steps given it
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4agv.png
I hope then you will be able to use addon ocrtesseract in your software